# Split function in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to split the address into two columns as streetno and streetname, say for ex
select address1 from customer

address for ex-look like

```
2719 STONE CREEK DR
```

and store them into street no as `2719` and streetname as  `STONE CREEK DR`.

using `split(address1 ,'[\ ]')[0]` just split the street no only.

it's just select statement we are using to view the data.

Sample data:

```
address1
100 HORACE GREELEY RD  
55 School Street
2893 MASHIE CIR
1200 JEWEL DR
201 W RIVER RD
```

Expected output

```
+--------------+---------------------+
| streetnumber |     streetname      |
+--------------+---------------------+
|          100 | HORACE GREELEY RD   |
|           55 | School Street       |
|         2893 | MASHIE CIR          |
|         1200 | JEWEL DR            |
|          201 | W RIVER RD          |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Not clear. Add to your original post a data sample with multiple rows that reflects your real data + requested result (in table format).

Comment: just added, hope this helps

Comment: So the number is **always** first?

Comment: @dudu Markovitz Yes

Comment: O.K., and why are you forcing a solution? `split` is only one option

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz I just tried with split but couldn't get the required output.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  regexp_extract(address1,'(.*?)\\s',1)   as streetnumber
       ,regexp_extract(address1,'\\s(.*)' ,1)   as streetname 

from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+----------------+--------------------+
| streetnumber   |     streetname     |
+----------------+--------------------+
| 100            | HORACE GREELEY RD  |
| 55             | School Street      |
| 2893           | MASHIE CIR         |
| 1200           | JEWEL DR           |
| 201            | W RIVER RD         |
+----------------+--------------------+
```

#### or

```
select  regexp_extract(address1,'.*?(?=\\s)',0) as streetnumber
       ,regexp_extract(address1,'(?<=\\s).*',0) as streetname 

from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+----------------+--------------------+
| streetnumber   |     streetname     |
+----------------+--------------------+
| 100            | HORACE GREELEY RD  |
| 55             | School Street      |
| 2893           | MASHIE CIR         |
| 1200           | JEWEL DR           |
| 201            | W RIVER RD         |
+----------------+--------------------+
```

#### or

```
select  split(address1,'\\s')[0]      as streetnumber
       ,split(address1,'^.*?\\s')[1]  as streetname 

from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+----------------+--------------------+
| streetnumber   |     streetname     |
+----------------+--------------------+
| 100            | HORACE GREELEY RD  |
| 55             | School Street      |
| 2893           | MASHIE CIR         |
| 1200           | JEWEL DR           |
| 201            | W RIVER RD         |
+----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: how to escape the special character in pyspark 

regexp_extract(accountaddress1,'(.\*\?)\\s',1) 

This query is running in hive but fails in pyspark